# Отловить клик TChromuim

Tags: delphi

Перейду сразу к делу

Есть кнопка на html странице, страница загружена в TChromium

```
<button>Это кнопка!</button>
```

Как при клике на эту кнопку выполнить процедуру?

Comment: Боюсь, что никак - `HTML` и Делфи не *знают* друг о друге.

Comment: Когда запускаешь делфи xe и выше на странице приветствия вставлен webbrowser а в него html только там internet explorer

Comment: Да, я знаю про это, но боюсь Embarcadero как-то хитро реализует эту фичу. Даже не представляю как. В любом случае предлагаю изучить эти доки: [CEF1](https://code.google.com/archive/p/delphichromiumembedded/) и [CEF3](https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3). Я *бегло* пробежался по коду - ничего такого, что можно использовать в Вашем случае не нашел. Возможно, кто-нибудь здесь посоветует что-нибудь еще.